# Bind List to TabControl with usercontrols in MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have an abstract class `MyAbstractDataClass` and a few sub classes like `GeneralDataClass` and `DetailedDataClass`, `FooDataClass`.

For each subclass there is a UserControl that provides fields (TextBoxes) for the corresponding data. (GeneralUserControl, DetailedUserControl, FooUserControl).

My ViewModel contains an ObservableCollection<MyAbstractDataClass>, to which various instances of the respective subclasses are added. For example 1x GeneralDataClass, 2x DetailedDataClass and 2x FooDataClass.

I would like to achieve the following behavior: The view should consist of a tab control, which displays a tab for each class in the viewmodel list. In the tab an instance of the respective user control should be opened.

I got it to work without any problems when I explicitly create the user controls in View.xaml. Then the data binding and the management of the different UserControl instances works.
However, I can't get the TabControl to react dynamically, i.e. the tabs are bound to the ObservableCollection.
After some research i ended up with this code, which at least recognizes and binds the collection and also provides a corresponding UserControl for each tab. However, the databinding does not work and no different instances of the UserControls are created.

```
<TabControl Name="tabs" Grid.Row="1" TabStripPlacement="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GeneralData}">
                        <local:GeneralDataUserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailedData}">
                        <local:DetailedDataUserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FooData}">
                        <local:FooDataUserControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not explicitly declare a ContentTemplate for the TabItems.

This is done automatically when the different DataTemplates are declared as resources of the TabControl (or one of its parent elements).

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding List}" ...>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GeneralData}">
            <local:GeneralDataUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailedData}">
            <local:DetailedDataUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FooData}">
            <local:FooDataUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

You must also make sure that the UserControls do not explicitly set their own `DataContext` property. Data templating like this only works when the controls in the DataTemplate get the inherited DataContext value of their parent element, i.e. a TabItem here.